# ErrorMessageResourceType set via method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources

I'm trying to change my DTO from something like this:

```
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Name")]
            [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "error msg")]
            [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
            public string Name { get; set; }
```

to something like this using resources:

```
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = ResourcesKeys.Name, ResourceType = typeof(res))]
            [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = ResourcesKeys.NameFieldTooLongErrorMsg, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(res))]
            [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
            public string Name { get; set; }
```

where **res** is my resource file. The app will have many resource files. This works fine for now but I'd like to know if there is any way of achiving the same result but by sending resource type via other method.

I'd like to have a class:

```
public static class ResourcesKeys
    {
        public const string Name  = "name";
        public const string NameFieldTooLongErrorMsg = "nameFieldTooLongErrorMsg";


        public static Type ReturnResourceType() 
        {
            return typeof(res); 
        }
}
```

that would help me to achieve:

```
[MaxLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = ResourcesKeys.NameFieldTooLongErrorMsg, ErrorMessageResourceType = ResourceKeys.ReturnResoureType())]
```

Now when I try to do this, line is underlined and the error says:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.

And I get it, you can't do it like this. I've tried to change it to

```
 [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = ResourcesKeys.NameFieldTooLongErrorMsg, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ResourceKeys.ReturnResoureType()))]
```

and the msg is this time as follows:

> The type name ReturnResourceType does not exist in the type
>   ResourceKeys.

and it's perfectly understandable. ReturnResourceType() is not a type, but a method. I get it. 
What I don't get is, is there any way to make it work like this?